# Copy the last element of an array into a different position, and then remove it from the end of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm looking for a neat (single-statement) method for copying the last element of an array into a different position (overriding an existing element), and then removing it from the end of the array.

Another way of looking at it is: swap between the element at a given index and the element at the last index, and then remove the element at the last index.

I can do it like so:

```
function func(array, index) {
    array[index] = array[array.length - 1];
    array.length--;
    return array;
}
```

And like so:

```
function func(array, index) {
    array[index] = array.slice(-1)[0];
    array.pop();
    return array;
}
```

And of course, any "hybrid" of the two functions above.

Is there a single-statement method for achieving that?

I was thinking of `splice`, but I'm a little unsure of how to actually make it work.

Comment: Your first function is probably the most efficient. Using `.slice()` or `.splice()` will involve a lot more copying.

Comment: @Pointy: Thank you. I care less about runtime efficiency and more about clean code. Would you happen to know how, even if `splice` costs more?

Comment: Well "clean code" is a subjective thing. Once you've isolated the operation in a function, nothing about  it seems "unclean" in my opinion.

Comment: @Pointy: Just realize I could do something like `return array.slice(0, index).concat(array.slice(-1)).concat(array.slice(index + 1, -1));`... But the two answers below are perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Well there's one thing you need to be aware of, ```length``` is a writeable property of an array and ```array.length --``` doesn't mean you have popped off the element. It's still there and can still be accessed.

Comment: @aaKhan that is not true. Setting the `.length` property to a smaller value removes elements from the end of the array.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```js
function func(array, index) {
    array[index] = array.pop();
    return array;
}

// Or
// const func = (array, index) => (array[index] = array.pop(), array);

const arr = func([1,2,3,4], 1);

console.log(arr);
```

To always remove the last element:

```js
function func(array, index) {
    if(index < array.length -1) array[index] = array.pop()
    else array.pop();
    return array;
}

// Or
// const func = (array, index) => (index < array.length -1 ? array[index] = array.pop() : array.pop(), array);

console.log(func([1,2,3,4], 1));

console.log(func([1,2,3,4], 3));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I've just realized, that doesn't work when `index == array.length - 1`.

Comment: it works, but you won't notice any change because you remove the element and reassign it to the same index.

Comment: Right, so that does not achieve the requirements which I have defined - first swap the elements (which will have no effect in this specific case), then remove the last element (which means that by the end, the last element should be out of the array). So you could say that "it works", but it works on a different problem than the one stated here. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's kinda nasty to put a statement (rather than a "non-active" expression) after the `?` operator. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pop()` and then assign it to the index requied. Because `pop()` returns the last element of array. You don't need to return array from function because it modifies the array.

```js
const func = (array, index) => array[index] = array.pop();
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4, 'last'];
func(arr, 2);
console.log(arr)
```

If you want the function to `return` the array too. You can use the `,` operator.

```js
const func = (array, index) => index === arr.length - 1 ? arr.slice(0, -1) : ((array[index] = array.pop()), array);
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4, 'last'];
console.log(func(arr, 5));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I've just realized, that doesn't work when `index == array.length - 1`.

Comment: @goodvibration What is expected output when `index == array.length - 1`. The original array or the array with last element removed?

Comment: The array with the last element removed. Remember - first step is to swap (which will have no impact in this case), second step is to remove. So by the end of the operation, that last element should be out of the array. Thanks.

Comment: @goodvibration I have updated the second version. Please check it.